# prove transactionHash of block using ethereumjs-tx and merkle-patricia-tree

Tags: transactions, merkle-patricia-tries, state-trie, ethereumjs-tx, merkleization

As an exercise I want to retrieve all transactions from a block and rebuild the merkle patricia trie, then compare the root hash with the transactionRoot stored in the block.  My current logic is receive block with complete transactions and then store each one in the trie using the necessary rlp encoding and serialization but I do not recreate the hash stored in the block.

for reference the block i am using can be found [here](https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getBlockByNumber&tag=0xA1A489&boolean=true&apikey=YourApiKeyToken)
the block hash is `0x441bcda29969fe4c94790b8538b70e30b66c62b69fe6516bea99634d290d16c7`

the four block transactions in raw format (from etherscan) are:
[tx0](https://0xb0c43213c86c2cacce8ceef965b881529d31e5be93ad6cefcef2f319a20ef1b5), [tx1](https://etherscan.io/getRawTx?tx=0x5bbbf64bd0f08465acbe30adb2be807488c3847c94a7dfabaffa3e25ab3a604a), [tx2](https://0xf86d8229f185199c82cc008252089488e9a2d38e66057e18545ce03b3ae9ce4fc360538702ce7de1537c008025a096e7a1d9683b205f697b4073a3e2f0d0ad42e708f03e899c61ed6a894a7f916aa05da238fbb96d41a4b5ec0338c86cfcb627d0aa8e556f21528e62f31c32f7e672), [tx3](https://0xf86f826b2585199c82cc0083015f9094e955ede0a3dbf651e2891356ecd0509c1edb8d9c8801051fdc4efdc0008025a02190f26e70a82d7f66354a13cda79b6af1aa808db768a787aeb348d425d7d0b3a06a82bd0518bc9b69dc551e20d772a1b06222edfc5d39b6973e4f4dc46ed8b196)

```
const { bufferToHex } = require("@ethereumjs/util");
const {Trie} = require("@ethereumjs/trie");
const {
    AccessListEIP2930Transaction: EIP2930Transaction,
    FeeMarketEIP1559Transaction: EIP1559Transaction,
    Transaction: LegacyTransaction,
} = require("@ethereumjs/tx");

const RLP = require("rlp");

const ethers = require("ethers");

const trie = new Trie();

/* 
    block that contains only 4 transactions 
*/
const blockHash = '0x441bcda29969fe4c94790b8538b70e30b66c62b69fe6516bea99634d290d16c7';

/*
    all 4 raw transactions copied from etherscan 
*/

const rawTxs = {
    tx0:'0xf8ab81a5852e90edd00083012bc294a3bed4e1c75d00fa6f4e5e6922db7261b5e9acd280b844a9059cbb0000000000000000000000008bda8b9823b8490e8cf220dc7b91d97da1c54e250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000056bc75e2d6310000026a06c89b57113cf7da8aed7911310e03d49be5e40de0bd73af4c9c54726c478691ba056223f039fab98d47c71f84190cf285ce8fc7d9181d6769387e5efd0a970e2e9'
    ,tx1:'0xf8ab81a6852e90edd00083012bc294a3bed4e1c75d00fa6f4e5e6922db7261b5e9acd280b844a9059cbb0000000000000000000000008bda8b9823b8490e8cf220dc7b91d97da1c54e250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000056bc75e2d6310000026a0d77c66153a661ecc986611dffda129e14528435ed3fd244c3afb0d434e9fd1c1a05ab202908bf6cbc9f57c595e6ef3229bce80a15cdf67487873e57cc7f5ad7c8a'
    ,tx2:'0xf86d8229f185199c82cc008252089488e9a2d38e66057e18545ce03b3ae9ce4fc360538702ce7de1537c008025a096e7a1d9683b205f697b4073a3e2f0d0ad42e708f03e899c61ed6a894a7f916aa05da238fbb96d41a4b5ec0338c86cfcb627d0aa8e556f21528e62f31c32f7e672'
    ,tx3:'0xf86f826b2585199c82cc0083015f9094e955ede0a3dbf651e2891356ecd0509c1edb8d9c8801051fdc4efdc0008025a02190f26e70a82d7f66354a13cda79b6af1aa808db768a787aeb348d425d7d0b3a06a82bd0518bc9b69dc551e20d772a1b06222edfc5d39b6973e4f4dc46ed8b196'

}

(async()=>{

    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider();

    const block = await provider.send("eth_getBlockByHash",[ blockHash, true ]);
    const results = await Promise.all(block.transactions.map((tx, i) => 
            (async (tx, i) => {

                /*
                    in block returned a transaction has 2 properties 'input' and 'gas'
                    that are expected as 'data' and 'gasLimit' 
                    modifications for ethereumjs 
                */

                tx.data = tx.input;
                delete tx.input;
                tx.gasLimit = tx.gas;
                delete tx.gas;

                let TransactionClass;

                switch (tx.type){
                    case '0x2' :
                        TransactionClass=EIP1559Transaction;
                        break;
                    case '0x1' :
                        TransactionClass=EIP2930Transaction;
                        break;
                    case '0x0' :
                        TransactionClass=LegacyTransaction;
                        break; 
                }

                const serializedTx = TransactionClass.fromTxData(tx).serialize();

                /*
                    check that serialized transaction matches etherscan raw transaction
                */

                console.log(rawTxs[`tx${i}`] === bufferToHex(serializedTx));

                return await trie.put(
                    RLP.encode(i),
                    serializedTx
                );

            })(tx, i) 
        ));

        console.log(`block.transactionsRoot: ${block.transactionsRoot}`)
        console.log(`trie.root: ${bufferToHex(trie.root)}`)        
})();
```

Comment: In order to rebuild the merkle patricia trie, you need to have the merkle patricia trie from the previous block. You can't just recreate the world state with the current block. You need to take the entire history into account.

Comment: @Donut thank you for your response.  I'm getting closer I think but I'm still not there.  When you say you need the MPT of the previous block how do you mean exactly?  I amended the above code to compare the transaction root with ancestor blocks but clearly that is naive. Do I have to include the transactions of another block when building the trie?

Comment: In order to get the current world state, you are required to start from block 1 and the transactions all the way to the current block. Imagine that block 1 has a transaction where 3 Eth are transferred from address 0x01 to 0x02. And that's it, these addresses are never touched again. The accounts are still part of the world state, but you will only get them in there if you replay the transaction from block 1. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My error was using `@ethereumjs/trie`'s `SecureTrie` class instead of `Trie` the above code works now